# EmEditorでダブルクリックした際の単語として認識される文字列に記号を加えたい

Tags: emeditor

文字列をマウスでダブルクリックすると単語が選択された状態になりますが、`-`（ハイフン）を含んだ単語を1単語と認識してほしく思っています。

現状 `_` （アンダースコア）を含んだ単語『aaa_BBB』はダブルクリックで選択されるんですが、`-` （ハイフン）を含んだ単語『aaa-BBB』は「aaa」or「-」or「BBB」しか選択してくれません。

プログラムソースなどを修正していると変数として設定されている単語をダブルクリックで選択できるようにしたいと思っており、
他には「$AAAAA」だったりコマンドオプションでよく使われる「-BBBB」とか「/A」とかも選択できるようにしたいのですが、どこの設定を変更すればよいでしょうか？

ご教授の程宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

[カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [編集] ページで、[次の文字を英数字として扱う] テキスト ボックスに、`_-$/` というように単語として認識したい文字を入力します。

[image: EmEditor - カスタマイズ - 編集]

Comment: おおっ！ありがとうございます。こんなところにあったんですね。

設定変更する場所がカスタマイズにある。という事は
拡張子毎に分ける。なんて事はできないという事ですよね？？

Comment: 残念ながら拡張子毎に分けることはできないです。

Comment: なるほどですね。わざわざ回答していただきありがとうございます。
レスが遅くなって申し訳ありませんでした。